# Transactions bottleneck Geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, private-blockchain, microsoft-azure

I have an ethereum consortium blockchain based on Azure.
I've been experimenting with an application which has a very simple smart contract, but may be data intensive(?).

The contracts itself, stores data that comes from the Javascript console (it's basically a mappping that maps to a structure of several strings).

**This has never happened before, so I was wondering if the issue would be the amount of times the geth loadscript command is invoked or the amount of data in each interaction (perhaps strings are too expensive?). I have however increased the genesis.json gas limit very much and each transaction has sufficient gas.**

My issue happens after interacting with the contracts a few times. The miner nodes keep mining blocks, but my transactions ceased to be mined (even transfers between the main account to a new account).
After a day or so, the transactions are mined, and the data structure is populated.

Either way, any feedback or request for additional information are much apprecieated,

Thanks

Comment: I never used ethereum on azure, so perhaps my suggestions do not apply there.  Using string is expensive, but your transaction should be processed anyway with an out of gas exception. Miners can delay processing transaction with low gas price, but in a private blockchain it should apply. Running out of ether, until the account has enough ether to pay for gas transaction will not be processed. Transaction nonce has to be incremental and consecutive, if you miss a nonce then all subsequent transaction will be stuck.